# Detect when popup closes and save the filled data before it is closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension with a popup. Popup has a form. Problem is :

Suppose user has filled half the form and decided to switch between the applications . When he returns, popup has been closed and he has to open the popup again and fill all the details again. I was thinking of saving data in `localStorage` before popup is closed. I have done this before in web pages using `window.onbeforeunload` and `window.unload` but these doesn't seem to work in popup.

Things I have tried:

1. Using `window.onbeforeunload`:

When I use `location.reload()` from *developers tools* (inspect popup), this event is fired and data is getting stored in localStorage. But during normal functioning(without developers tools and clicking outside the popup), this event is not fired(I confirmed by checking the value in `localStorage`)

2. Using  `chrome.runtime.connect`:

Connect to background page with `chrome.runtime.connect` and `port.onDisconnect` will be fired in the background page when the popup is closed. This will only tell me when popup is closed. Before I request data from popup, it has already been closed.

3. Using `window.unload`:

This seems to work for some people but having  I am having the same issue as `window.onbeforeunload`

4. Using `blur` event(works but not so efficient):

Adding `blur` on all input fields and when any of these input field loses focus, save all the filled values. It is fired even if user clicks outside the popup. But it is not an efficient way.

Is there any other alternative ??

Comment: Maybe try to save the data on text chaned or one of the following events
onchange, onkeypress, onpaste, oninput

Comment: Just note any of these will only fire when the input lost focus, eg, user went to press the button or clicked somewhere else.

Comment: You shouldn't put a form in the action popup. Instead, open a tab.

Comment: Yes I should probably do that. But I dont want to open a tab

Comment: It's perfectly fine (and common) to have forms in action popups. Unless you are saving the text to War and Peace the inefficiencies of saving a form on every blur to localStorage is going to be negligible.